# Find the last element of a list under conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Let's consider the following simple data list

```
data = {{0.516393, 0.0655738, 1.92, 0.0281531, 9}, 
        {0.811475, 0.639344, 0.67, 0.00546318, 1}, 
        {-0.286885, 0.203279, 0.1, 0.0104138, 1}, 
        {1.22131, 0.839344, 0.7, 0.0037756, 3}, 
        {0.745902, 0.462295, 0.81, 0.0046604, 2}, 
        {-0.0737705, 0.396721, 0., 0.0343436, 2}, 
        {-1.07377, 0.67541, 1.32, 0.0159418, 1}, 
        {-0.893443, 0.0557377, 1.76, 1.14265, 9}, 
        {-0.336066, 0.360656, 0.1, 0.0110171, 0}, 
        {-0.106557, 0.00983607, 16.71, 0.0000678431, 1}}
```

I use the following code

```
SelectFirst[data, ((-1.1 < #[[1]] < 1.1) && (#[[5]] == 1 || #[[5]] == 2 || #[[5]] == 3)) &];
```

for selecting the first row of the list with given conditions.

Now how can I obtain the last row of the list with the same conditions? In other words, is there any custom made `SelectLast`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `SelectFirst` with `Reverse`d first argument:

```
SelectFirst[Reverse @ data, 
  ((-1.1 < #[[1]] < 1.1) && (#[[5]] == 1 || #[[5]] == 2 || #[[5]] == 3)) &]
```

> {-0.106557, 0.00983607, 16.71, 0.0000678431, 1}

You can make it a function similar to `SelectFirst`:

```
selectLast[criterion_] := SelectFirst[criterion] @* Reverse
selectLast[d_, criterion_] := selectLast[ criterion] @ data

selectLast[ ((-1.1 < #[[1]] < 1.1) && (#[[5]] == 1 || #[[5]] == 2 || #[[5]] == 3)) &]@data
```

> {-0.106557, 0.00983607, 16.71, 0.0000678431, 1}

```
selectLast[data, ((-1.1 < #[[1]] < 1.1) && (#[[5]] == 1 || #[[5]] == 2 || #[[5]] == 3)) &]
```

> > {-0.106557, 0.00983607, 16.71, 0.0000678431, 1}

Comment: Thank you! I believe that `SelectLast` should also be included in the built-in functions of Mathematica.